# Why I am getting the altitude as 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why I am getting the altitude as 0 while using CoreLocation framework?

Comment: provide code examples, otherwise nobody will be able to help you

Comment: altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTITUDE: %gm", location.altitude];

Comment: %g is new to me, I think what you need is the correct format specifier, i am assuming it to be a float and you have to use %f for that.

Comment: i referred this tutorial.---->http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/18/ios-core-location-gps-tutorial-pt-2/

Comment: i tried %f also...it doesnt worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altitude comes from GPS. You need to be outdoors to get altitude.
Take your device outdoor and see if you are getting altitude.

Comment: Wrong. I've gotten altitude indoors.

Comment: You can get it but did you check verticalAccuracy? That could have been negative, the documentation mentions verticalAccuracy is available with GPS only. Also the LocateMe sample checks for verticalAccuracy and if it is negative then it shows altitude not available.

Comment: No, I got accurate altitude indoors.

Comment: GPS altitude is not reliable and there is obviously no such provision for altitude using WiFi for location. In general, vertical accuracy is 1.5x worse than horizontal accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
   altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f m",   newLocation.altitude];
     }
```

Comment: check this code http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/18/ios-core-location-gps-tutorial-pt-2/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are testing your application on your device, the altitude will always be 0 when the update comes from Wi-Fi. Try disabling Wi-Fi to force an update from 3G. Note that it may take a while until you get an update because 3G doesn't return a position as fast as Wi-Fi.

Comment: You should probably get an altitude reading in less than 5 minutes using an iPhone 3G or later, but it also depends on your phone operator and tower proximity. Install a free altimeter application from the App Store to check that you are able to receive altitude updates at your location.

Comment: I installed altimeter but it is also nt wrking and I am using iphone 3GS.